# "No package 'gsl' found when" when installing custom c++ libraries

Tags: gsl

I'm trying to install a custom c++ library - Milia http://guaix.fis.ucm.es/projects/milia/wiki

When I run `./configure` I get the error

```
configure: error: Package requirements (gsl) were not met:

No package 'gsl' found
```

I have GSL installed in the `/usr/local` directory and it works fine. Not exactly sure why it can't find gsl.

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the output of the following commands:  pkg-config --cflags gsl and pkg-config --libs gsl ? And which GSL version you have?

Comment: Another shot is set the following enviroment variables : GSL_CFLAGS and GSL_LIBS in milia configure

Comment: I've got GSL v1.16.. running the pkg-config commands tell me:
"Package gsl was not found in the pkg-config search path."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment, the solution of your problem is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320267/package-opencv-was-not-found-in-the-pkg-config-search-path) (just follow the steps of the updated answer that is written inside the question and adapt the flags to the GSL flags).

PS: if you only want to make Milia work and not fix the fact the dpkg can't find your gsl installation, then you can just update GSL_CFLAGS and GSL_LIBS environment variables. If defined, Milia will use them instead of asking dpkg for the gsl path

Extract from configure file

> GSL_CFLAGS  C compiler flags for GSL, overriding pkg-config
>
> GSL_LIBS    linker flags for GSL, overriding pkg-config

After that, just relax and let Milia show you how dark energy impacts distances and ages in FRWL metric! :)

Comment: Worked except instead of adding the two lines to ~/.bashrc I had to add them to ~/.bash_profile

Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: ok. If it worked, you should mark this answer as the right one to close the question @Seth