# Pip cannot locate opencv

Tags: python, opencv, installation, pip, homebrew

I am trying to install xbob.flandmarks using "pip install xbob.flandmark". When I do so I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: PkgConfig did not find package opencv. Output:

Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path.

Perhaps you should add the directory containing `opencv.pc'

to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable

No package 'opencv' found
```

This is a somewhat common error (see [here](http://prateekvjoshi.com/2013/10/18/package-opencv-not-found-lets-find-it/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320267/package-opencv-was-not-found-in-the-pkg-config-search-path)). I have tried the solution these links propose (adding the opencv.pc file to my `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` both by exporting it in the shell (`export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/2.4.8.2/lib/pkgconfig/`) and by adding the line to my `~/.bashr`c file. I have also tried using the opencv.pc file stored in the homebrew Cellar as well as in `/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`.)

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: is the output of `pkg-config --libs --cflags opencv` empty?

Comment: Forgot to mention that I'm running on mac (I assume this is the reason --libs returns command not found)

Answer (score 1):

Type `pip install opencv-python`.

It should be good.

Answer (score 1):

I would got with `pip install opencv-contrib-python`

The opencv-contrib-python repository contains both the main modules along with the contrib modules — this is the library I recommend you install as it includes all OpenCV functionality. This could make sure you cover the stuff making your error above.

Ref: https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/19/pip-install-opencv/