# Failing to compile opencv program with g++

Tags: c++, opencv, g++, raspberry-pi

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Input:

```
pi@raspberrypi ~/DisplayImage $ g++ DisplayImage.o -o DisplayImage `pkg-config --cflags opencv` `pkg-config --libs opencv`
```

Output:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_core.so.2.4, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../libopencv_contrib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_imgproc.so.2.4, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../libopencv_contrib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_features2d.so.2.4, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../libopencv_contrib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_calib3d.so.2.4, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../libopencv_contrib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_highgui.so.2.4, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../libopencv_contrib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_ml.so.2.4, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../libopencv_contrib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_video.so.2.4, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../libopencv_contrib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libopencv_objdetect.so.2.4, needed by /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../libopencv_contrib.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6/../../../libopencv_core.a(rand.cpp.o): undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_getspecific@@GLIBC_2.4'
//lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: You should check the outputs of the two pkg-config commands to see if they make sense.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](http://answers.opencv.org/question/27106/error-undefined-references/) has the arguments the other way around.

```
pkg-config opencv --libs
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are cross compiling you may need `pkg-config-arm-linux-gnueabi` reading the similar post might also help [Package opencv was not found in the pkg-config search path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320267/package-opencv-was-not-found-in-the-pkg-config-search-path)