# Make can't find my opencv.hpp file - how to direct it?

Tags: c++, opencv, makefile, raspberry-pi

I have a dual camera hardware module for my raspberry pi zero.  It requires some software to get working though.  I have cloned [the required repo](https://github.com/ArduCAM/RaspberryPi) from, as seen here:

```
pi@luna:~/RaspberryPi/Multi_Camera_Adapter/Multi_Adapter_Board_2Channel_uc444 $ ls
arducam_multi_adapter_uc444.cpp  Makefile  obj  readme.md  shell
```

When I try to make, I get the following error:

```
pi@luna:~/RaspberryPi/Multi_Camera_Adapter/Multi_Adapter_Board_2Channel_uc444 $ sudo make
g++ -c -o obj/arducam_multi_adapter_uc444.o arducam_multi_adapter_uc444.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`  
arducam_multi_adapter_uc444.cpp:4:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:10: obj/arducam_multi_adapter_uc444.o] Error 1
```

Looking at `/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2` I see the file this script wants.

```
pi@luna:~/RaspberryPi/Multi_Camera_Adapter/Multi_Adapter_Board_2Channel_uc444 $ ls /usr/include/opencv4/opencv2
alphamat.hpp     ccalib           dnn_superres.hpp  freetype.hpp  imgcodecs                line_descriptor.hpp  opencv_modules.hpp    quality       shape                 superres              video          ximgproc
aruco            ccalib.hpp       dpm.hpp           fuzzy         imgcodecs.hpp            mcc                  optflow               quality.hpp   shape.hpp             superres.hpp          video.hpp      ximgproc.hpp
aruco.hpp        core             face              fuzzy.hpp     img_hash                 mcc.hpp              optflow.hpp           rapid.hpp     stereo                surface_matching      videoio        xobjdetect.hpp
bgsegm.hpp       core_detect.hpp  face.hpp          hdf           img_hash.hpp             ml                   phase_unwrapping      reg           stereo.hpp            surface_matching.hpp  videoio.hpp    xphoto
bioinspired      core.hpp         features2d        hdf.hpp       imgproc                  ml.hpp               phase_unwrapping.hpp  rgbd          stitching             text                  videostab      xphoto.hpp
bioinspired.hpp  datasets         features2d.hpp    hfs.hpp       imgproc.hpp              objdetect            photo                 rgbd.hpp      stitching.hpp         text.hpp              videostab.hpp
calib3d          dnn              flann             highgui       intensity_transform.hpp  objdetect.hpp        photo.hpp             saliency      structured_light      tracking              viz
calib3d.hpp      dnn.hpp          flann.hpp         highgui.hpp   line_descriptor          opencv.hpp           plot.hpp              saliency.hpp  structured_light.hpp  tracking.hpp          viz.hpp
```

I tried to create an opencv.pc as described in [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15320267/package-opencv-was-not-found-in-the-pkg-config-search-path), but the opencv.hpp is still not being found.

```
pi@luna:~/RaspberryPi/Multi_Camera_Adapter/Multi_Adapter_Board_2Channel_uc444 $ cat /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/opencv.pc 
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
includedir=${prefix}/include
libdir=${exec_prefix}/lib

Name: opencv
Description: The opencv library
Version: 2.x.x
Cflags: -I${includedir}/opencv -I${includedir}/opencv2
Libs: -L${libdir} -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_core -lopencv_ml -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_flann -lopencv_video -lopencv_highgui
```

I felt like that opencv.pc is not point to the right place as it resolves to `/usr/include/opencv2` and on my pi, I have the files in `/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2`, though even with tinkering with where the opencv.pc file points, I'm still running into the error above.  I have since returned it to its original state and have modified my `.bashrc` as they suggested.

```
pi@luna:~/RaspberryPi/Multi_Camera_Adapter/Multi_Adapter_Board_2Channel_uc444 $ pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
-I/usr/include/opencv -I/usr/include/opencv2 -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_core -lopencv_ml -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_flann -lopencv_video -lopencv_highgui
pi@luna:~/RaspberryPi/Multi_Camera_Adapter/Multi_Adapter_Board_2Channel_uc444 $ echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH
:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

I feel like something needs to be linked or pointed to somewhere to get make to see that `opencv.hpp` file.  If I go in and manually edit `arducam_multi_adapter_uc444.cpp`'s 4th line to the absolute path of the `opencv.hpp`, I no longer get an error in `arducam_multi_adapter_uc444.cpp`, but in `opencv.hpp` as it then is included and starts looking for `core.hpp` and other `.hpp`s in `/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2`.  How can I fix this, I feel close, I just don't know how to tell make where to look.

Comment: Try put `-I/usr/include/opencv4` when compiling. You're searching the header file `/usr/include/opencv2/opencv.hpp` which is actually in `/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with make per se.  The problem is that your compiler invocation is wrong for the include statement you have.

You can debug this yourself: first, see the command make invoked:

```
g++ -c -o obj/arducam_multi_adapter_uc444.o arducam_multi_adapter_uc444.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Now run that command yourself from your shell prompt.  You'll see it fails the same way.  So you know it's not make, but rather the compiler command that's wrong.

Next, figure out what the `pkg-config` is expanding to; run that from your shell prompt:

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
```

It will print out the options it's adding.  These options are wrong and causing your compile to fail.

First, you are compiling a source file into an object file, so you don't need the `--libs` option.  The `--libs` option provides libraries to *link* with and these are not used during compilation.

Second, your configuration says this:

```
Cflags: -I${includedir}/opencv -I${includedir}/opencv2
```

which means the compiler will see options like `-I.../include/opencv -I.../include/opencv2`.  There's no magic to the way header files are looked up: the compiler takes the paths provided by `-I`, and appends the path it needs from your `#include` line, one by one, until the header is found.  That's all.

Since you're including `opencv2/opencv.hpp`, it will add that path to each of the `-I` paths.  So, the compiler looks for `.../include/opencv/opencv2/opencv.hpp` first, then it will look for `.../include/opencv/opencv2/opencv2/opencv.hpp`.

Clearly, the header you want is not available at either of those paths: the header you want is (presumably) `.../include/opencv2/opencv.hpp`.

So, if you want your `#include` to specify `opencv2/opencv.hpp`, your cflags need to be:

```
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

Comment: Thanks this is helpful.  Modifying the opencv.pc as I believe it should be, I have `pi@luna:~/RaspberryPi/Multi_Camera_Adapter/Multi_Adapter_Board_2Channel_uc444 $ pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv
-I/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2 -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_core -lopencv_ml -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_flann -lopencv_video -lopencv_highgui`.  So that should be pointing to the opencv4/opencv2/opencv.hpp that I want, but I'm still getting the compile error.

Comment: No.  Look again, more carefully.  Your `-I` option is:  `-I/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2`.  Your `#include` file is `opencv2/opencv.hpp`.  When the compiler appends these two paths together it gets `/usr/include/opencv4/opencv2/opencv2/opencv.hpp` (note, `opencv2` appears twice in a row here).  That's wrong.  You didn't change your config the way I suggested.

Comment: Also, as I said, you should remove the `--libs` option from the compiler command.  It's useless (and may generate warnings in some compilers) to add linker options like `-l` to compile lines.  Those should only appear in link lines.

Comment: Sweet a new error has emerged.  The march of progress goes on.  Thanks for the help and your patients.