# How to build Opencv code in a docker file

Tags: c++, docker, opencv, docker-compose, dockerfile

I want to build and run a c++ **opencv** code using docker. Here is my dockerfile:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.5.0-cudnn8-runtime-ubuntu20.04
FROM ubuntu

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    g++ git wget cmake sudo

RUN apt-get install -y \
    build-essential cmake git libgtk2.0-dev pkg-config libavcodec-dev libavformat-dev libswscale-dev \
    python3-dev python3-numpy libtbb2 libtbb-dev libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libdc1394-22-dev \
    libcanberra-gtk-module libcanberra-gtk3-module

RUN git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git && \
    cd /opencv && mkdir build && cd build && \
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D    CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local .. && \
    make -j"$(nproc)" && \
    make install  && ldconfig
```

The above commands makes my opencv libs, but I don't how to use it to run the actual code. I added this two lines at the end of the dockerfile (wav.cpp is the name of my cpp file that I want to run):

```
COPY . .

RUN g++ -o wav wav.cpp
```

But at the end I get this error, which obviously says it can't find the opencv headers.

> wav.cpp:2:10: fatal error: opencv2/imgproc.hpp: No such file or
> directory
> 2 | #include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
> |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.

Now how should I resolve this header (and lib) dependency problem?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [@emrhzc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58290585/5832272) I could build my code inside the dockerfile. Now my final working command is:

```
RUN g++ -o wav wav.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the location for the headers and which libraries should be linked by `gcc`. Please take a look at the manual of `gcc/g++` for the flags `-I` and `-L`. Should be something like this:

```
RUN g++ -o wav wav.cpp -I <opencv header location> -L <opencv libs location> -lopencv_core ....
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually that's my problem, when we build inside docker, where will be those locations to specify?

Comment: based on your make command should be `/usr/local/include/opencv4` for headers and `/usr/local/lib/` for libraries..